# How to typecast a value based on the struct field type?

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a method that fill fields on the given `struct`, but to set the right value i need to convert the value to check if the type matches the struct field type.

Example:

```
type S struct {
    Name string
    Age int
}
```

The value will alwayt be `string` because it came from a URL.

```
const stubQuery = "name=sam&page=30"
query, _ := url.ParseQuery(stubQuery)
// e.g result: {"name": ["sam"], "age": ["30"]}
```

I've manage to iterate over the `query` and get the field from `S` struct, but how can i get the field type and cast the "30" to the struct type?

```
structValue := reflect.ValueOf(&S{}).Elem()
structFieldValue := structValue.FieldByName("Age")

structFieldType := structFieldValue.Type()
val := reflect.ValueOf("30")

if structFieldType != val.Type() {} // Always false
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear @zerkms, i need to convert the string based on the struct field type, so if the field is `int` i need to convert to int and if the field is `float` i need to convert it to `float`

Comment: Convert it to int first, if it failed - try to convert it to float.

Comment: The field is dynamic, I can't predict what type it will be

Comment: My latest suggestion does exactly what you asked. If you meant something else - please correct the question accordingly.

Comment: No, it does not, you just said to try to convert to `int` and if i get an error try to `float`, but i'm trying to explain that the struct field could be any type, `int/int32/int64/float/time/bool`, again, what i'm asking is if there's a way to convert the "value" to the struct field type.

Comment: There is nothing built-in for that, you either need to implement it from scratch or use a 3rd party library, eg: https://github.com/gorilla/schema

Answer (score 0):

The application must parse the string to a value assignable to the field.

Find the type or [kind](https://godoc.org/reflect#Kind) to parse using [type switches](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) and value switches.

Use the [strconv package](https://godoc.org/strconv) to parse numeric values and bools.  Use the [time package](https://godoc.org/time) to parse times and durations.

Here's some sample code:

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(&s).Elem()
t := v.Type()
for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
    sf := t.Field(i)

    // Get value from query. Skip if not set.
    values, ok := query[strings.ToLower(sf.Name)]
    if !ok || len(values) == 0 {
        continue
    }

    // Use type switch for specific types.
    switch f := v.Field(i).Addr().Interface().(type) {

    case *time.Time:
        var err error
        *f, err = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, values[0])
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    case *time.Duration:
        var err error
        *f, err = time.ParseDuration(values[0])
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

    default:
        // The specific type was not handled. Fallback
        // to using the field kind. This allows us to
        // handle all numeric and bool types without knowing
        // those types explicitly.

        switch sf.Type.Kind() {
        case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
            n, err := strconv.ParseInt(values[0], 10, sf.Type.Bits())
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            v.Field(i).SetInt(n)
        case reflect.Uint, reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64:
            n, err := strconv.ParseUint(values[0], 10, sf.Type.Bits())
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            v.Field(i).SetUint(n)
        case reflect.Float64, reflect.Float32:
            n, err := strconv.ParseFloat(values[0], sf.Type.Bits())
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            v.Field(i).SetFloat(n)
        case reflect.Bool:
            b, err := strconv.ParseBool(values[0])
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            v.Field(i).SetBool(b)
        case reflect.String:
            v.Field(i).SetString(values[0])
        default:
            log.Fatal("unknown type")
        }
    }
}
```

Types are checked first so that time.Duration is parsed as a duration instead of as an integer.

Replace the calls to log.Fatal with the error handling appropriate for your scenario.

[Run it on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/g8Ihwz-MzI5).

Answer (score -1):

```
val := reflect.ValueOf("30")
```

The type of incoming arguments (`"30"` in your sample code) is *string*. Its type will never match the type of a numeric field.

You have to inspect `structFieldType`, to determine what transformation you should apply to `val`.

Another way could be to add a specific method to your struct to populate it's fields :

```
AssignFields(in url.Values) error
# or
AssignField(name string, value string) error
```